# How can I create a Map of my nested List objects in java?

Tags: java, list, recursion, java-stream

I have a list: `List<XNode> nodes` and every `XNode` has an `ArrayList<XNode> children;` and `int id;` as member variables. How can I create a `Map<ParentId, ChildId>` of all my nodes in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it would be impossible to create a *map* of parentId to each childId if there is a *list* of children in each node because in general case a `parentId` key may have multiple `childId` values and this conflict has to be resolved somehow.

So, either a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` where `List<Integer>` contains ids of all children, or a `List<List<Integer>>` (where the inner `List<Integer>` contains a pair of `parentId` and `childId`) may be created.

And finally, it needs to be defined whether the result contains *roots* or *leafs*.
The difference may be described as: *roots* have their `parentId = null` and non-null `childId`, *leafs* always have non-null `parentId` while `childId` may be `null`.

Let's assume the input list of nodes is defined like this:

```java
List<XNode> list = Arrays.asList(
    new XNode(1, Arrays.asList(new XNode(11, Arrays.asList(new XNode(111), new XNode(112))), new XNode(12), new XNode(13))),
    new XNode(2),
    new XNode(3, Arrays.asList(new XNode(31, Arrays.asList(new XNode(311)))))
);
```

Then the map may be created as follows:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = list.stream()
    .flatMap(Main::flatMapEntry)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new
    ));  
System.out.println("map example: " + map);
```

with a recursive method `flatMapEntry`:

```java
static Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>> flatMapEntry(XNode node) {
    return node.getChildren().isEmpty()
        ? Stream.of(Map.entry(node.getId(), Collections.emptyList()))
        : Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(Map.entry(
                node.getId(), 
                node.getChildren().stream()
                    .map(XNode::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            )),
            node.getChildren().stream().flatMap(Main::flatMapEntry)
        );
}
```

Output for the given input (10 keys, 13 values):

> map example: {1=[11, 12, 13], 11=[111, 112], 111=[], 112=[], 12=[], 13=[], 2=[], 3=[31], 31=[311], 311=[]}

---

Examples of building the lists of pairs:

- Traversing the `List<XNode>` by breadth:

```java
List<List<Integer>> leafsBreadth = flatList(list).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("leafs(breadth): " + leafsBreadth.size() + ": " + leafsBreadth);
// ---
static Stream<List<Integer>> flatList(List<XNode> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> x.getChildren().isEmpty() 
            ? Stream.of(Arrays.asList(x.getId(), null)) 
            : Stream.concat(x.getChildren().stream()
                .map(c -> Arrays.asList(x.getId(), c.getId())),
                flatList(x.getChildren())
        ));
}
```

Output:

> leafs(breadth): 13: [[1, 11], [1, 12], [1, 13], [11, 111], [11, 112], [111, null], [112, null], [12, null], [13, null], [2, null], [3, 31], [31, 311], [311, null]]

---

- Traversing the `List<XNode>` by depth (per each `XNode` in the list):

```java
List<List<Integer>> leafsDepth = list.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> flatChildren(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("leafs(depth):   " + leafsDepth.size() + ": " + leafsDepth);
// ----
static Stream<List<Integer>> flatChildren(XNode node) {
    return node.getChildren().isEmpty()
        ? Stream.of(Arrays.asList(node.getId(), null))
        : node.getChildren().stream().flatMap(x -> Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(Arrays.asList(node.getId(), x.getId())),
            flatChildren(x)
        ));
}
```

Output:

> leafs(depth):   13: [[1, 11], [11, 111], [111, null], [11, 112], [112, null], [1, 12], [12, null], [1, 13], [13, null], [2, null], [3, 31], [31, 311], [311, null]]

---

- Building *roots* by depth

```java
List<List<Integer>> rootsDepth = list.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> flatRoots(null, x)) // using null for missing parentId
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("roots(depth):   " + rootsDepth.size() + ": " + rootsDepth);
// ----
static Stream<List<Integer>> flatRoots(Integer parentId, XNode node) {
    return Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(Arrays.asList(parentId, node.getId())),
        node.getChildren().stream().flatMap(x -> flatRoots(node.getId(), x))
    );
}
```

Output:

> roots(depth):   10: [[null, 1], [1, 11], [11, 111], [11, 112], [1, 12], [1, 13], [null, 2], [null, 3], [3, 31], [31, 311]]